# How to set a click event for button in repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am doing a social network service using asp.net/c#, I have little problems with accepting friends request. I display those friends request on repeater control, and that repeater control has confirm button and reject bottom. once user press confirm button a sql query will be executed.

This is that sql query

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
         conn.Open();
         try
         {



             string inserQuery = "Update [Friendship] Set Friend_Status = 1 WHERE Friend1 ='" + Session["Email"] + "' And Friend2='" + Session["temmp"] + "'";
             SqlCommand commm = new SqlCommand(inserQuery, conn);
             commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Friend1", Session["Email"].ToString());
             commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Friend2", Session["Temmp"].ToString());




             commm.ExecuteNonQuery();


           //  Label1.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();



    }
```

Session [email] is = User Login email, temmp [email] is = User who sent a friend request.

I don't know how to get temmp[email] to my Friendship table

this is my repeater control code

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>


    <div style="border-top: thin none #91ADDD; border-bottom: thin none #91ADDD; padding: 10px;  width: 548px; margin-top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #F6F6F6; border-left-color: #91ADDD; border-right-color: #91ADDD;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"><%#Eval("YourName") %></asp:Label>

            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="wants to be a friend !!!"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <div style="width: 58px; height: 40px">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ProfilePicPath") %> ' Width="55px" />
                <div style="width: 318px; margin-left: 176px; margin-top: -10px; height: 27px;">
                </div>
            </div>
    <div style="margin-top: -20px">
            <asp:Button ID="Confirm" runat="server" style=" margin-left: 250px; margin-top: 11px;" Text="Confirm" Width="98px" CommandName="confirm" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Reject" runat="server" Text="Reject" Width="98px" />
    </div>
&nbsp;<div style="width: 431px;  margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#3b5998"><%#Eval("YourName") %> </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="status" style=" width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px;">
                &nbsp;<br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEmail" runat="server"CommandArgument=
    '<%# Eval("Email") %>' CommandName="mail"><%#Eval("Email") %></asp:LinkButton>        
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"  />
            </div>
            &nbsp;
        </div>

 </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is i tried code behind code

```
  private void Repeater3_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)

 {
     switch (e.CommandName)
     {
         case "mail":
             string emailId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
             break;
     }
     Session["temmp"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

     if (e.CommandName == "confirm")
     {


         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
         conn.Open();
         try
         {



             string inserQuery = "Update [Friendship] Set Friend_Status = 1 WHERE Friend1 ='" + Session["Email"] + "' And Friend2='" + Session["temmp"] + "'";
             SqlCommand commm = new SqlCommand(inserQuery, conn);
             commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Friend1", Session["Email"].ToString());
             commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Friend2", Session["Temmp"].ToString());




             commm.ExecuteNonQuery();


           //  Label1.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();



    }

 override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnInit(e);

     Repeater3.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(Repeater3_ItemCommand);


 }
```

I only want when someone click confirm button Friendrequest sender's email should be equal to Session[temmp]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `OnClick` event for `Button` as below, no need of specifying `CommandName`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEmail" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Email") %>' OnClick="LinkEmail_Click"><%#Eval("Email") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

And in code-behind you can add event call

```
protected void LinkEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string emailId = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: but i cannot click button on repeater, once i click it, it gives me error, like postback......

Comment: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: try by not using `CommandName`, like above code and remove `OnInit` event

Comment: And I don't see repeater in your question. Can you add it?

Comment: I have edited my answer as you asked to get email string in code behind

Comment: Remove `ItemCommand` related code and try above edited code for `LinkButton`. If it works as you expected you can add `OnClick` for other bottons.

Comment: I meant styling, Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) for link button

Comment: You can add `CssClass` attribute for `LinkButton` and you can also add `Style` attribute

Comment: can i show linkbutton as a normal button using CSS?

Comment: You can, but if you want to show as normal button, you can use normal button itself

Comment: [thanks i did it,](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10882127_1507636016192641_7792088772123225105_n.jpg?oh=02375dae20d03e60fea2614c423df740&oe=54FC0E57)